# MSXML2.XMLHTTP response different from IE document

Tags: vba, excel

I want to know why in some cases the HTML in the response from `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object does not produce the same results as automating Internet Explorer and inspecting the `document` property value.

For example, the procedure below compares the results found by using the object `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` (column A) with the results found by using the `InternetExplorer` object (column B).

The results of the  `InternetExplorer` object  include the NASDAQ index  as expected but the results of the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object do not include the NASDAQ index and are completely different:

```
Sub ExtractDataFromInternet()
'Enable Tools/references 1. Microsoft Internet Control and 2. Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Dim URL
Dim objHTML As HTMLDocument
Dim Oelement As Object
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim J, Field1, Field2

    Set objHTML = New HTMLDocument
    URL = "http://www.nasdaq.com/"

    '-------- METHOD1: MSXML2.XMLHTTP --------------------------
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    objHTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    J = 0
    Set Field1 = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each Oelement In Field1
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(J + 1, 1) = Field1(J).innerText
    J = J + 1
    Next Oelement

    '----------METHOD2: InternetExplorer Object----------------
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = False
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Wend
    Set objHTML = .document
    DoEvents
    End With
    J = 0
    Set Field1 = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each Oelement In Field1
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(J + 1, 2) = Field1(J).innerText
    J = J + 1
    Next Oelement
    DoEvents
    ie.Quit
    DoEvents
    Set ie = Nothing
    '----------------------------------------------
    End Sub
```

Comment: I guess in method 2 you got modified by scripts HTML content (DHTML), and in method 1 it is raw server response (simple loading the response into HTMLDocument won't link that scripts since location is `about:blank`).